# Make pulseaudio ignore USB sound card

Tags: pulseaudio, soundcard

I am running Jack to driver an external USB card (Focusrie Scarlett 18i8). When I plug the card in, pulse sometimes takes over the card and jack cannot be started (it needs exclusive access to the device).

What is the way to make pulseaudio ignore the 'hw:USB' ALSA device?